# Why say "it rhymes with Grape"?

Tags: dialogue, 21-jump-street

There is a scene in 21 Jumpstreet where Dave Franco' character Eric says "do you know what they'll do to me in prison it rhymes with grape" and it made me curious as to why it was phrased that way.

In Knocked Up a similar joke was made "it rhymes with smabortion" which I believe I read was done due to censors. However the repeating setup for the joke has me curious if this time it was due to censors or if it was just considered a funny setup that bared repeating. So was it censoring or continuing a joke?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Opinion: It was a funny(?) joke.**

Although a similar setup was used in *Knocked Up*, the truth is similar setups have been used in plenty of comedy movies.

Whilst I understand your query regarding the censors, it seems difficult to imagine *why* censorship would be an issue, the main reason I can think of being:

- There is a colossal amount of crass language, violence, partial nudity and drug taking in the film. Why would all this be considered acceptable but a line about rape wouldn't be?

It seems more likely to me that it was a funny line that works in the context of the scene as it seems so abhorrent that he *can't bring himself to utter the actual word*, instead resorting to childish rhyming (suggesting the mere thought of it makes him regress to his inner child in fear).

Whether it was a homage to his (extremely popular) line from *Knocked Up* is something I can find no reference to online, but solely in my own opinion, I can't see how this was a censorship issue.

Comment: I think this setup has been used time and time again through many different movies. It's just a setup to make it seem funnier than if they just came out and said it outright. I doubt there is any real connection between the two movies or the lines themselves.